# Using python socket with raspberrypi.local as ip

Tags: python, pi-zero, pi-zero-w, sockets

I have a raspberrypi zero 1.3 and am connecting to it by enabling local ssh as instructed [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/turning-your-raspberry-pi-zero-into-a-usb-gadget/ethernet-gadget) and using raspberrypi.local as the ip to connect with using putty and winscp. I would like to connect to my raspberrypi using the python socket module. I am currently trying to do so like this:

client on pi:

```
import socket 
import logging 

ip = 'raspberrypi.local'
port = 12345 

log = logging.getLogger()

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, s.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    log.info("Binding to {}".format(ip))
    s.bind((ip, port))
    log.info("Listening to {}".format(ip))
    s.listen()
    log.info("Accepting {}".format(ip))
    conn, addr = s.accept()

    if not conn and not addr:
        log.error("Accepting failed")
        os.system("pkill python")
    log.info('Accepted {}'.format(self.ip))

while True:
    json_data = self.conn.recv(1024)
    if not json_data:
        break
    ...
```

server on desktop:

```
import socket 
import logging 
import threading

device_ip = 'raspberrypi.local'
device_port = 12345 
device_socket = None

log = logging.getLogger()

def makesock():
    global device_socket
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.connect((self.device_ip,self.device_port))
    device_socket = s
    else:
        log.exception("socket retrieval failed")
        raise ConnectionError
    return


log.info("connecting to remote device: {} {}".format(device_ip,device_port))
sock = threading.Thread(target=makesock, args=("device",))
sock.start()
seconds = 0
while not device_socket and seconds < 10 and sock.is_alive():
    log.info("waiting for connect: {}".format(seconds))
    seconds+=1
    sleep(1)
if not self.device_socket:
    log.exception("remote device not found: {} {}".format(device_ip,device_port))
else:
    log.info("connected to remote device: {} {}".format(device_ip,device_port))
```

Using a different pi and a regular 192.168... ip address this works without a problem. However, switching to the raspberrypi.local ip causes the following error on the pi:

```
Traceback ...
    self.socket.bind((self.ip, self.port))
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

The same thing happens when I use localhost. Is there a particular reason this problem keeps occuring like that?

Comment: The name raspberrypi.local is not associated with the IP address.  Could be many reasons, none of which are specific to the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: `raspberrypi.local` is NOT an IP. This is a Windows problem as it treats .local in a non standard way.

Comment: Use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` (or `::1` for IPv6) not the mDNS name and your program will bind to the loopback interface (which isn't useful for anything other than sending to a program running on the same machine). Use `0.0.0.0` (or `::` for IPv6) to bind the the `INADDR_ANY` address and your program will bind to the interface with the default route. That's what you really want here.

Comment: @Dougie I tried using ´localhost´ and ´127.0.0.1´ as the device_ip on the client and the server but the server keeps giving me the error message ´remote device not found: localhost 12345´. This happens after 2 seconds regardless of whether the connected raspberrypi is looking to accept or not. Is there something else I am not taking into account here?

Comment: DON'T use localhost, 127.0.0.1 or ::1, your program will never work.